# TFS 2015 copy output to remote server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

Using Team Services, I have a build server which performs my continuous integration builds. Is there any way to copy the build output to a remote server?

This remote server is not linked in any way to the build server in terms of network or domain, but I have full control of the firewall.

I have set up WinRM on the remote server, but I have not successfully made the build server connect to it.

How can I copy all output files to the build server?

Comment: Does your build agent has the access to the remote server?

Comment: Access in what sense? I have full control of the build server, and the remote server, and their firewalls. They are not connected through network or VPN though.

Comment: I mean the internet access.

Comment: Yes the build server can access the remote server through the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a "[Windows Machine File Copy](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/WindowsMachineFileCopy)" task in your definition to copy the output to the remote server.

And you can following this link if you want to configure WinRM: [How to Run PowerShell Commands on Remote Computers](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/).

Comment: Thank you - I'll take a look this evening and report back.

Comment: It turns out that everything was already setup correctly. The reason why none of it worked was because you must use [MACHINE-NAME]\[USERNAME] for the admin user in the TFS settings. I was just using the username. Strange because WinRM tests didn't require the machine name. Your URLs helped me reach this conclusion though, so thank you.